# accessing creativeUrl or adformLandingPage of the creatives through linkedin api

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to access creativeUrl and adformLandingPage of the creatives running at linkedin platform, but all the time getting an error "not enough permissions to access field creativeUrl for GET /adCreativesV2/92971226".

My token is including all the necessary scopes (r_ads_reporting, r_organization_social, rw_ads, rw_organization_admin, w_organization_social) and I can query the creatives belonging to the account themselves (e.g. https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/127103184) but the outcome does not include the needed fields. That is not leads based ads, so URLs should exist and I see it as "Click URL" at the csv reports loading manually from linkedin platform. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2/127103184?fields=creativeUrl"

payload={}
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
response = response.json()
```